# Using Ethernet ports on Moca enabled modem/router with moca 2.0 technology

Tags: networking

I believe I have got my configuration figured out to best set up my Moca network. I live in a town which uses its own cable service for internet and cable tv. I've recently canceled my cable subscription to move towards a much cheaper YouTube TV plan, thus wanting all of my TVs to be hard wired for internet. Obviously my tvs(4 total) are all mounted right next to a coax jack, with the coax cable for all rooms having their own individual coax cable that ends up at the box on the side of my house where my isp has the service coming in. Those particular cables are all disconnected(qty 4), with one other coax cable connected to my isp which runs to my Hitron modem/router. I'm 99% sure that with my Hitron modem/router having moca 2.0 technology, i should be able to add a moca filter right after the connection to my isp, then add a "moca" splitter to hook up my disconnected (TV)coax cables along with the cable that runs to my modem. Then it should be as easy as hooking up moca adapters in between my TV and their respective coax outlets. First i'd love to know if that part is correct. Secondly, what should I do about the empty jack that would be left on the moca splitter?

The main reason for this post however, is to figure out if the ethernet ports are still functional on my modem/router when moca is enabled. I currently use all 3 of its ethernet ports for a hard wired ethernet connection to my PC as well as ethernet connections to my gaming consoles.

MAIN CONCERN: With moca enabled on my Hitron coda-5519 modem/router, can I still use the ethernet ports.

What should probably be the main concern: Is the setup I laid out correct, and if so do I need to put anything over the empty jack that'll be left on the splitter I'd be using?

Comment: I'm not quite picturing why you'd have an open connection on a splitter. It sounds like you need a 1:2 splitter between your MoCA POE filter and your Hitron, and the other leg of that splitter goes to a 1:4 splitter, connecting to the 4 lines to the 4 TVs. Where's the empty connector?

Comment: So it's funny that you responded with this. I was originally going to use a 6 way.. after making this post i decided to do exactly as you said. Now, with my modem/router being moca enabled or having moca technology built in, do I strictly need a moca poe filter before rhe first 2 way splitter? I don't need one on the "in" port of the 4 way splitter?

Comment: @Spiff also if I have it setup like you've said with the correct splitter setup, moca poe filter in the correct location, and my hitron coda-5519 being moca enabled, can i use the the 3 ethernet ports to keep my connection to my 2 consoles and my PC?